# Making android application using pubnub to send GPS information but app crashes and shows no errors

Tags: java, android, android-logcat, android-location, pubnub

I am making an application that sends  realtime messages through a pubnub server to users that are subscribed to the same channel. I have it working so that I can send strings from device to device, but now I want to send GPS information. The user will input a string "GPS" and that will trigger a method to then send the location info instead of that string. I am having trouble with this part because no errors are shown, but the app crashes when I try to open it. I tried debugging, but I can figure out whats going wrong. The debugger takes me out of my activity and into these other java class files that are embedded in java after I get step over the oncreate method. Any help or feedback would be really appreciated, thanks!

---

Some errors I found in the logcat:

ADB:

```
    ddms: null
    java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:182)
        at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.movePacket(JdwpPacket.java:235)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.sendAndConsume(Debugger.java:347)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.forwardPacketToDebugger(Client.java:698)
        at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:344)
        at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)
```

---

Device LogCat:

```
03-20 15:44:56.780  15612-15612/com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub E/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file
03-20 15:44:56.780  15612-15612/com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub E/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file
03-20 15:44:56.780  15612-15612/com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub E/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_SAMSUNG-SGH-I257_4.2.2_0025
03-20 15:44:56.780  15612-15612/com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub E/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub/com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2835)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
            at com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:221)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1202)
            at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5404)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.pubnub.api.Callback;
import com.pubnub.api.Pubnub;
import com.pubnub.api.PubnubError;
import com.pubnub.api.PubnubException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //Button to subscribe to user specified pubnub channel
    private Button channelSubscribeButton;
    private EditText subscribeChannelEditText;
    private TextView messageLogTextView;

    //Button to send message to other devices subscribed on same channel
    private Button sendMessageButton;
    private EditText sendMessageEditText;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    private double lat;
    private double lon;
    private double accuracy;

    private MainActivity activity;


    //-------------------------Access PubNub API-------------------------//

    //pubnub publish and subscribe keys
    Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("pub-c-", "sub-c");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Subscribing and sending messages
        channelSubscribeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribe_button);
        subscribeChannelEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.channel_name);
        messageLogTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_log_text_view);

        sendMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_message_button);
        sendMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_edit_text);

        activity = this;


        //Get location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //Define criteria for how to select the location provider --> use default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


        //Prints GPS provider if there is or isn't one
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            //messageLogTextView.append("GPS Information Not Available");
        }

    }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    public void onChannelButtonClick(View view) {


        //Get the user inputted text in
        String subscribeChannel = String.valueOf(subscribeChannelEditText.getText());
        String yourSubscribeChannel = "Subscribed to the " + subscribeChannel + " Channel";


        Toast.makeText(this, yourSubscribeChannel, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
            pubnub.subscribe(subscribeChannel, new Callback() {

                        @Override
                        public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                            Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : CONNECT on channel:" + channel
                                    + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                                    + message.toString());
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                            Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel
                                    + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                                    + message.toString());
                        }

                        public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                            Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + channel
                                    + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                                    + message.toString());
                        }

                        //Updates textview with message
                        @Override
                        public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                            Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                                    + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
                           updateTextView(message.toString() + "\n");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                            Log.d("PUBNUB", "SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + channel
                                    + " : " + error.toString());
                        }

                    }
            );
        } catch (PubnubException e) {
            Log.d("PUBNUB", e.toString());
        }


    }

    public void updateTextView(final String message) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    messageLogTextView.append(message);
                } catch(Exception ex) {

                    Log.d("pubnub", ex.getMessage());
                }
                messageLogTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            }
        });


    }

    public void onSendMessageButtonClick(View view, Location location) {


        String messageToSend = String.valueOf(sendMessageEditText.getText());

        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {

            }

            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                Log.d("PUBNUB", error.toString());
            }
        };

        String subscribeChannel = String.valueOf(subscribeChannelEditText.getText());

        pubnub.publish(subscribeChannel, messageToSend, callback);

        //if the user input string is equal to "GPS" then initialize the onLocationChanged method
        //if not, print to the string to the log textview
        if(messageToSend.equals("GPS")) {

            //Print to the textview log the onLocationChanged
            onLocationChanged(location);

        } else {

            updateTextView("GPS cannot be retrieved");

        }

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, (LocationListener) this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
    }


    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    //method to retrieve location information
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
        double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
        float accuracy = (float) (location.getAccuracy());
        double alt = (double) (location.getAltitude());
        double speed = (double) (location.getSpeed());
        double heading = (double) (location.getBearing());

        messageLogTextView.append(String.valueOf(lat));
        messageLogTextView.append(String.valueOf(lng));
        messageLogTextView.append(String.valueOf(accuracy));
        messageLogTextView.append(String.valueOf(alt));
        messageLogTextView.append(String.valueOf(speed ));
        messageLogTextView.append(String.valueOf(heading ));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is this (in the middle of the stack trace you provided):

```java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.location.LocationListener
  at com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:221)
```

Examining `MainActivity.onResume`, it turns out that you're casting your `MainActivity` to `LocationListener`. You'll need to implement `LocationListener` if you want to be able to pass `MainActivity` to `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates`.

To do this, first check the documentation for [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html). There are four abstract methods, you've implemented two of them so far - `onStatusChanged`, and `onLocationChanged`. You need to implement `onProviderEnabled`, and `onProviderDisabled`. Then, change your class declaration to:

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! If you don't mind, could you go into a little more detail as to how I would go about implementing          LocationListener?

Comment: Sure, I added that to the answer!

Comment: I think that solved that problem, but now its crashing at a different spot in the code where the user presses the send button



  ` 23684-23684/com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onSendMessageButtonClick(View) in the activity class com.example.kunalpatel.pubsub.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'send_message_button' `

I dont think I'm formatting the code correctly...sorry

Comment: That error is due to the fact that you're calling `onSendMessageButton(View)`, when you've only defined `onSendMessageButton(View, Location)`. If you run into these kinds of errors a lot, I suggest using an IDE which will help you locate them ahead of compile time (Android Studio is one nice option).

Comment: lol embarrassing...I am using android studio...

I don't understand your explanation as to why calling that method is a problem, can you clarify? If I'm calling the the method and I've defined it, why is that a problem?

Comment: You're only calling `onSendMessageButtonClick(View)`, not `onSendMessageButtonClick(View, Location)`. The two parameter lists are different.

Comment: In the code I have posted, it shows `onSendMessageButtonClick(View view, Location location)` . That is also how I have it in my code that I am running and still getting that error.

Comment: Reread the error message: `Could not find a method onSendMessageButtonClick(View)`. That is a different method to `onSendMessageButtonClick(View view, Location location)`. The first takes one parameter, the second method takes two.

Comment: Yeah but no where in the code do I call only `onSendMessageButtonClick(View)`.

Comment: It's an `onClick` handler, it's getting called when the view is clicked. The one parameter `View` is how the callback is defined, you have to change your implementation, i.e. remove the `Location` parameter from _your_ method.

Comment: If I remove the Location parameter, how can I call the `onLocationChanged` method?